# Conjugaison avec le groupe « plus d'un »

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Je lisais un article et je suis tombé sur une règle de français qui m'échappe.

Deux phrases similaires utilisaient le groupe sujet *« plus d'un »* et accordaient le verbe différemment, une au singulier, l’autre au pluriel.  Pourtant, intuitivement, je serais porté à accorder le verbe toujours au pluriel! C'est spécifié qu'il y a **plus** d'un <*insérer un objet quelconque*>, donc on peut déduire qu'il y en a au minimum deux.

Les phrases en question sont les suivantes :

- Accord au singulier :

  > Plus d'une question est posée chaque jour.
- Accord au pluriel

  > Plus d'un membre se supportent l'un et l'autre.

Quelqu'un peut m'éclairer à ce sujet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En effet, cela peut sembler étrange à première vue, mais en fait c'est plutôt simple. Il y a principalement quatre cas possibles.

Il est bien aussi de préciser qu'il y a deux éléments à considérer lors de l'accord :

- La conjugaison du verbe, à la troisième personne du singulier ou du pluriel;
- L'accord du participe passé, lorsqu'il y en a un, avec le genre (masculin, féminin) et le nombre (singulier, pluriel) du sujet.

---

1. #### *Cas général* Lorsque le groupe sujet du verbe est composé de « plus d'un » :

   L'accord se fait alors avec le nom qui suit « un », qui est singulier. Le premier exemple entre dans cette catégorie :

   > Plus d'une question est posée chaque jour.

   Dans ce cas, le verbe se conjugue avec « question », qui est un nom féminin singulier.

   *Note :* Le nom n'est pas obligé d'être explicite et peut être sous-entendu selon le contexte. Dans ce cas, l'accord se fait avec le nom sous-entendu (qui est singulier). Par exemple :

   > Plus d'un connait la réponse à cette question.
2. #### Le groupe « plus d'un » est suivi d'un complément pluriel :

   Dans ce cas, l'auteur de la phrase peut choisir l'accord en fonction d'où il veut mettre l'accent dans la phrase. Par contre, dans la majorité des cas on utilise le singulier. Par exemple :

   > Plus d'une *des questions* du site est retweetée chaque jour.

   Dans ce cas-ci, l'accord se fait avec « une », qui représente littéralement « une des questions ». On accorde donc au féminin singulier. Si on avait eu « plus d'un » on aurait conjugué le participe passé au masculin singulier.

   *Par complément pluriel, j'entends tout groupe composé d'un déterminant et d'un nom exprimant le pluriel. Par exemple : « plus d'un de mes collègues », « plus d'un des kiwis », etc.*
3. #### Lorsque le groupe verbal exprime une action réciproque :

   Les verbes avec le pronom « se » (verbes pronominaux) en sont un exemple. Dans ce cas, puisqu'il y a plusieurs éléments *participant* à l'action, il faut conjuguer le verbe au pluriel. Le deuxième exemple entre dans cette catégorie :

   > Plus d'un membre *se supportent* l'un et l'autre.

   Dans ce cas, on conjugue le verbe au pluriel, car il y a au moins deux membres *impliqués* dans l'action.
4. #### Lorsqu'il y a deux sujets avec « plus d'un » :

   Dans ce cas, puisqu'il y a deux sujets, on suit la règle normale d'accord pour les sujets multiples et on conjugue le tout au pluriel. Par exemple :

   > Plus d'un homme, plus d'une femme fêteront ce soir.
   >   Plus d'un étudiant et plus d'une étudiante verront leurs cours complétés ce soir.

---

*Pour plus d'exemples, voici [l'article de l'OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1701), duquel je me suis inspiré.*

Comment: Merci de votre réponse. En fonction du 3e cas, vous rédigez que ... puisqu'il y a plusieurs éléments participant à l'action, il faut conjuguer le verbe au pluriel. Ce raisonnement, pourquoi ne s'applique-t-il pas aux 1e et 2e cas histoire que la phrase "plus de X" soit toujours suivie par le pluriel? Je pensais que "plus de X" impliquent > 1 éléments participant à l'action figurée et marquée par le verbe.

Comment: @LePressentiment effectivement, « plus d'un » signifie qu'il y a plusieurs personne, mais on accordent généralement avec le « un ». La nuance entre le premier cas et le troisième cas est qu'au premier cas, on pose chaque question séparément. Chacune des questions est posée. Tandis que dans le troisième cas, il faut nécessairement au moins deux membre pour effectuer l'action (verbe pronominaux) de « se supporter ». Le mot clé est vraiment le « se » qui impliquent une action avec plusieurs sujets. Je ne sais pas si cela répond à votre question! Sinon faites moi le savoir.